# What is the derivative of $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am ask to find the most general antiderivative of $f(x)= x^n$ where $n \geq 0$.

However, I wondering how the derivative of  $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ is equal to $x^n$

My answer is $x^n - x^{n+1} $

Is my algebra at fault? 
[image]

Comment: You're differentiating with respect to $x$. $dn/dx=0$, so your second term is wrong.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: n is just a constant.  your only variable is x.  For example, try differentiating $\frac{1}{2} x^2$

Comment: The antiderivative is $\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, not $\dfrac{x^n+1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ is a constant, so you can't apply $\dfrac{u}{v}$ rule here like that. Instead, differentiate like this,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x^{n+1}\right)=\frac{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1-1}=x^n$$

Comment: Are you using the product rule? The denominator multiplied by the derivative of the numerator?

Comment: @Cetshwayo, Product rule ($uv$ rule) or quotient rule ($\frac{u}{v}$ rule) while differentiating w.r.t. $x$ are applicable when both $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and not some constant. But here, we have a constant. So, we use here the following identity: $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(kf(x))=k\cdot \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x)~\textrm{where }k\textrm{ is a constant}$$

Comment: Even if you think about product rule or quotient rule, note that $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)=0$, so it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I would like to say that yes you can use the product or quotient rule! There's no restriction saying you can only use it if $u,v$ are non constant.

Comment: @avid19, ah yes, I noticed that later. Hence, the second comment. :)

Comment: If we know the derivative of $x^n$ is $ \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1} $, then what can we conclude?

Comment: @GohP.iHan, Are you talking about derivatives in parallel universe? Because in our universe, we have, $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}\neq \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: Oh. I meant to say the ANTIderivative.

Comment: In that case, both the approaches are equivalent because differentiation and integration are inverse operations of each other.